# What are the open set of the circle?

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb S^1=\{e^{it}\mid t\in [0,2\pi]\}$ What are the open set of $\mathbb S^1$ ? I know also that $\mathcal S^1=\{(x,y)\mid x^2+y^2=1\}=\{(\cos(\theta ),\sin(\theta ))\mid \theta \in[0,2\pi]\}=[0,1]/_{0\sim 1}$, but I don't see how to find the open set of such sets ?

May be, in $[0,1]/_{0\sim 1}$ open set are the $U$ s.t. $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is open in $[0,1]$ where $\pi(x)=x$ if $x\in (0,1)$ and $\pi(0)=\pi(1)$. So, all sets of the form $(a,b)$ for $a,b\in(0,1)$ will be open, but this does really make sense for me since $(a,b)$ are interval of $\mathbb R$ not of $\mathbb S^1$... Any help would be welcome (because I'm a bit lost with these topological question)

Comment: If you want to use the reciprocal images of continuous functions, you must consider that $\mathbb S$ is also a topological group for which then the functions $(x, y)\to xy$ and $x\to \dfrac 1x$ are continuous by definition. But you can also use the topology induced by the topology product of $\mathbb R^2$ and exhibit a base of openings or neighborhoods. (Remember $x$ and $y$ are points of the circle, so couples $(a,b)$)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that the image of $(a,b)$ under the quotient map $\pi \colon [0,1] \to S^1$ is the set $\{e^{i 2\pi t} \mid t \in (a,b)\}$ with $0<a<b<1$. So this is an open set in $S^1$ because the preimage of this set is also $(a,b)$. The only other place you need to check is the end points of the interval. What is the preimage of the set $\{e^{i 2\pi t} \mid t \in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\}$ in $[0,1]$ for instance?

Once you've answered that, you've found a basis for the topology, and so every other open set is a union of those.

Comment: So my projection was wrong. It should have been $t\mapsto e^{2i\pit}$, right ? But $\pi(x)=x$ if $x\in (0,1)$ and $\pi(0)=\pi(1)$ should work no ?The preimage of $\{e^{2i\pi t}\mid t\in (-\varepsilon ,\varepsilon )\}$ is $[0,\varepsilon )\cup (1-\varepsilon ,1]$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I'm implicitly using the fact that you know $[0,1]/{\sim}$ is homeomorphic to $S^1 \subset \mathbb{C}$. That is the correct preimage! Is the preimage open?

Comment: Thanks. Yes the pre-image is open in $[0,1]$. Thanks